# Choosing cells in a struct with specific conditions

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

Data looks more like this:

```
T = struct('Direction',
           {[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1],[2,2,2,2,2],
            [2,2,2,2,1,2], [2,2,2,2,2],[3,1,4,5]},
           'Tr‌ial', 
           {'correct','incorrect','incorrect','correct','correct','incorrect'});
```

this is just an example and i have other fields as well

```
T = T(arrayfun(@(x) all(x.Direction == 2), T));
```

I already have the above code which works fine but it only gives me the `[2,2,2,2,2]` and it does not give me the cell with `[2,2,2,2,1,2]` because it also has 1.

I tried using `<= 2`  but it includes the `[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2,1]` as well. Is there a way to do this? I want to get 2 things:

1. cells that contain `ALL 2 OR ALL 1` and allow for maximum one element
   that is different so then I can get both `[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,1,2]`
   unlike my code that gives only `[2,2,2,2,2]`
2. cells that contain random numbers

I really appreciate your any help.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the condition to

```
sum( x.Direction == 2 ) + 1 >= numel( x.Direction )
```

This should return `true` even if one of the elements is `1`

Comment: thanks for the answer. there is no error for the code but I still don't get the cells with [2,2,2,2,1,2].